# writing oracle insert query which prevents from inserting duplicated rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to write a query which prevents inserting duplicated rows as below

```
INSERT INTO RSS_SETTING_ADMIN (ID_PRODUCT , ID_RSS , ID_CATEGORY , ID_TYPE_USER)
VALUES (384 , 3, 283 , 1)WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM RSS_SETTING_ADMIN 
WHERE ID_PRODUCT = 384 , ID_RSS = 3 , ID_CATEGORY = 283, ID_TYPE_USER = 1)
```

but I receive

> SQL command not properly ended

error

Comment: Look into the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)  statement

Comment: When you post about error messages you receive, please post the entire error message (including the line and position). In this case, the error message points directly to the problem: the word "WHERE". Then you can check the documentation, you will find there is no place for a WHERE clause in an INSERT statement with a VALUES clause. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2111652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
INSERT INTO RSS_SETTING_ADMIN (ID_PRODUCT , ID_RSS , ID_CATEGORY , ID_TYPE_USER) 
SELECT 384 , 3, 283 , 1 FROM  DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM RSS_SETTING_ADMIN 
  WHERE ID_PRODUCT = 384 
        AND ID_RSS = 3 
        AND ID_CATEGORY = 283 
        AND ID_TYPE_USER = 1
);
```

I also remember you that is not sufficient to prevent duplicate rows , you need a unique key for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to this

```
INSERT INTO RSS_SETTING_ADMIN (ID_PRODUCT , ID_RSS , ID_CATEGORY , ID_TYPE_USER)
select 384 , 3, 283 , 1 
from dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM RSS_SETTING_ADMIN 
                  WHERE ID_PRODUCT = 384 and ID_RSS = 3 
                         and ID_CATEGORY = 283 and ID_TYPE_USER = 1
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the insertion of duplicate values, then you should use a unique constraint/index on the table:

```
alter table RSS_SETTING_ADMIN
    add constraint unq_RSS_SETTING_ADMIN_4 unique(id_product, id_rss, id_category, id_type_user);
```

It is a much better approach to let the database maintain relational integrity rather than the application.

If you do want to still use `not exists`, I would recommend:

```
insert intoRSS_SETTING_ADMIN (ID_PRODUCT , ID_RSS , ID_CATEGORY , ID_TYPE_USER)
    select x.id_product, x.id_rss, x.id_category, x.id_type_user
    from (select 384 as id_product, 3 as id_rss, 283 as id_category, 1 as id_type_user
          from dual
         ) x
    where not exists (select 1
                      from  RSS_SETTING_ADMIN rsa
                      where rsa.id_product = x.id_product and 
                            rsa.id_rss = x.id_rss and
                            rsa.id_category = x.id_category and 
                            rsa.id_type_user = x.id_type_user
                      );
```

With this structure, the values are only included in the query once, which makes it easier to avoid typos.